# Getting gradient from voxel, is it possible and how?

Tags: mesh, plotting, r, 3d

The R package **rmarchingcubes** implements a marching cubes algorithm. Given a voxel contructed from a function defining an isosurface, it returns a 3d mesh with some vertex normals. When I plot this surface, it is incredibly smooth. If instead of the **rmarchingcubes** normals, I use the classical normals obtained by averaging the surrounding faces, the plot is not as smooth. If I use the gradient of the function to get the normals, it is smooth.

So it is clear that **rmarchingcubes** does not compute the classical vertex normals. But when I run it, I don't give the function, I only give the voxel. So I'm wondering whether it is possible to approximate the gradient from the voxel? And if it is possible, how?

Comment: How do you weigh the normals to compute the average?

Comment: @nicoguaro I tried three different ways: unweighted, area weighted, and a weighting based on some angles.

Comment: None of them gave you the "smoothness" that you wanted?